# How to implement a PUT call with JSON data using AJAX and JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, put

I've looked around and tried many different methods, but can't seem to pass actual data to my controller's function.

Here is some code:

```
        var URL = "/Timesheet/Timesheet/UpdateEntry";

        var dataObject = { 'newWeekEntry': newEntry, 'oldWeekEntry': oldEntry };

        alert(JSON.stringify(dataObject));

        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'PUT',    
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                alert("success?");
            }
        });
```

`newEntry` and `oldEntry` are both objects.

The `alert` line outputs this (with some properties removed, just for brevity):

```
{"newWeekEntry":{"MondayHours":2,"TuesdayHours":2,"WednesdayHours":5,"ThursdayHours":5,"FridayHours":"4","SaturdayHours":0,"SundayHours":0},"oldWeekEntry":{"MondayHours":2,"TuesdayHours":2,"WednesdayHours":5,"ThursdayHours":5,"FridayHours":2,"SaturdayHours":0,"SundayHours":0}}
```

When I debug my controller action ("UpdateEntry"), the two parameters are filled with the `TimesheetEntry` class default parameters (0).

Am I passing this in properly?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean when you say "When I debug my controller action ("UpdateEntry"), the two parameters are filled with the TimesheetEntry class default parameters (0)."?  What are you using on the server (i.e. Rails) and how are you converting JSON on the server to TimesheetEntry?

Comment: The `dataType` attribute is only used when you're getting data from the server.  You should be setting `contentType` to `application/json` when sending data to the server.

Comment: Thank you InPursuit! That fixed it. Would you like to add this as an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `dataType` attribute is only used when you're getting data from the server. You should be setting `contentType` to `application/json` when sending data to the server.

Answer (score 6):

```
$.ajax({
        url: window.serverUrl + 'student/event/' + eventId,
        type: 'put',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'x-auth-token': localStorage.accessToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        dataType: 'json'
})
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Use headers: `{"X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT"}` and override the `POST` request type. It works on my project...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // Use POST with X-HTTP-Method-Override or a straight PUT if appropriate.
    dataType: 'json', // Set datatype - affects Accept header
    url: "http://example.com/people/1", // A valid URL
    headers: {"X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT"}, // X-HTTP-Method-Override set to PUT.
    data: '{"name": "Dave"}' // Some data e.g. Valid JSON as a string
});
```

Comment: Why use 'POST' as the type but override it in the headers?

Comment: Look up and you will see that put as a type doesn't work as should be

Comment: And how to get the in your controller?

Comment: This only works with those servers that understand that header, as a workaround for lacking support for the 'PUT' or 'DELETE' methods.  It's awful.

Comment: Sorry, I should say that it's awful, as it introduces security concerns.  If you can legitimately and properly do a PUT request, do so.