# jQuery AJAX PUT has empty QUERY_STRING and REQUEST PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, put

I am writing a web front-end to an existing REST interface which I developed. So far, all my POST and GET requests have been working fine, but when I started adding a PUT request, now I have trouble.

I boiled this down to a very simple test case with 2 files:

My javascript AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "putTest.php",
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    data: { testVar: "test" },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function( data ) {

    },
    failure: function( data ) {

    }
});
```

And my PHP page "putTest.php":

```
<?php

    var_dump($_SERVER);

?>
```

I would expect, like in a GET or POST, that my QUERY_STRING server variable would include `testVar` which is the data I passed to it. However, that is not true, look at the response:

```
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "PUT"
["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) ""
["REQUEST_URI"]=>  string(25) "/test/putTest.php"
```

What is puzzling me is that I used a Firefox plugin (HttpRequester) and sent the exact same parameters and settings and the response came back perfectly as expected.

Why won't the parameters come across when using the jQuery AJAX?

Thanks!

Comment: see if this Q&A helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032938/jquery-ajax-put-with-parameters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056810/how-to-implement-a-put-call-with-json-data-using-ajax-and-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749272/jquery-how-to-put-json-via-ajax

Comment: wow... very interesting. Basically, PUT and DELETE don't accept data, so i would have to add it to the URL (similar to a GET request). Is that correct?

Comment: @KivakWolf No just check my answer

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't know but you could try it. I like to help out by finding links to related questions when I am sometimes unable to fully provide a solution.

Comment: It shouldn't have data in QUERY_STRING.  PUT, like POST puts the data into the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default php does not support DELETE/PUT ....

```
<?php
function getRequestParams() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET" || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
        return $_REQUEST;
    } else {
        // For urlencode
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $var);
        // or for json content
        // $var = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

        return $var;
    }
}

$params = getRequestParams();
```

$params would have your submitted params

Way you parse would depend on dataType you submit with.

Comment: @KivakWolf  NP, Had this problem before.